# node.js reading null string at the end of file

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to read and print file in Node.js(6.10.2) but it prints a null string at the end

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('aaa.xml', 'utf-8', function (data, err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

It is working fine when I print with Python. What could the reason be?

Comment: Presumably `(data, err)` is a typo and you actually have `(err, data)`?

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed the data and the err in the callback function. So, the data was in the err variable and the err was in the data variable.

This should work fine

```
 var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile('aaa.xml', 'utf-8', function (err,data){
    if(err) console.log(err);

    console.log(data);
    });
```

For more details refer to:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback